# split whitespace and special character in java

Tags: java

```
input = "Apple|contact issues  problems|add contact";
```

how to split above string in java. I tried with split("\s{2,}")but by using this split for only multi whitespace. but I want below output.

```
output:
Apple
contact issues
problems
add contact
```

Comment: Add the pipe char to your regex : `input.split("\\s{2,}|\\|"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to keep alpha beta and numeric.

You can use the below regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]|\s{2,}
```

Any character is not match a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and single space will be split.